# I am trying to read a pdf file from android mobile memory but its showing "load pdf error"

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_pdf_viewer);
        pdfView=(PDFView)findViewById(R.id.pdfView);
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        url = extras.getString("url");
        Uri uri=Uri.parse(url);
 pdfView.fromUri(uri)
 .pages(0, 2, 1, 3, 3, 3) 
                        .enableSwipe(true)
                        .swipeHorizontal(true)
                        .enableDoubletap(true)
                        .defaultPage(0)
                        .enableAnnotationRendering(false)
                        .password(null)
                        .scrollHandle(null)
                        .enableAntialiasing(true)                        
                        .spacing(2)
                        .autoSpacing(true) 
                        .pageFitPolicy(FitPolicy.WIDTH)
                        .fitEachPage(true) 
                        .pageSnap(true) 
                        .pageFling(true)
                        .nightMode(false) 
                        .load();
            }
```

The file is located on the given file-path: */storage/emulated/0/Android/data/edu/files/101.pdf* **and I am getting the correct path everywhere but still getting below error:**

*2020-10-30 02:58:17.947 7146-7146/edu E/PDFView: load pdf error
java.io.FileNotFoundException: No content provider: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/edu/files/101.pdf*

**I have tried up to my limit but not able to find the error please guide me where I am wrong?**

Comment: `url` is a filesystem path, not a `Uri`. Do not use `Uri.parse()`. Use `Uri.fromFile(new File(url))`.

Comment: It's working fine.You really saved my life... Thanx a ton.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A useful `Uri` has a scheme, such as `content`, `https`, or `file`. `Uri.parse()` will parse a bare filesystem path, but it does not put `file` in as the scheme, and the resulting `Uri` usually is useless.

So, if you have a filesystem path as a string, and you need a `Uri`, use `Uri.fromFile(new File(...))`, where `...` is that path.